NextJS App Router - how to add noscript tag in head to include some css style when JS is switched off
I would like to include some noscript styles in NextJS with App router. I have a layout.tsx (server component), which includes Metadata. In the same file I have html tag and head tag. I need a simple css class to be there, like
.wrapper { display: block }

Code snippet:
import { Metadata, Viewport } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "title",
  description: "description",
};

export const viewport: Viewport = {
  width: "device-width",
  initialScale: 1,
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <noscript>???</noscript>
      </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

